# Handle batch request limits using the Google API PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

On this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch, it says:

> You're limited to 50 calls in a single batch request. If you need to make more calls than that, use multiple batch requests.

Do I still need to manually break up my set of requests if they exceed 50 when using the client library? Or does the client library automatically break them up for me?

I'm following this guide: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/batch

Comment: I am pretty sure you will have to handle that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DalmTo is correct. I need to manually break up my set of requests. The client library does not handle that on its own.